# Matplotlib not plotting intermittently

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Novice user.

I have been using Matplotlib on Jupyter/Colab notebooks until recently and plotting worked fine.

Recently the plotting behaviour has somehow changed, and I can't figure out what's changed.

%matplotlib inline has been set.

This works fine: (outputs a plot in the output cell)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y1 = [1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3, 1]
y2 = [2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2]
plt.plot(x, y1, label="line L")
plt.plot(x, y2, label="line H")
plt.plot()

plt.xlabel("x axis")
plt.ylabel("y axis")
plt.title("Line Graph Example")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**But this does not:** (does not show anything in the cell output)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def random_plots():
  xs = []
  ys = []

  for i in range(20):
    x = i
    y = np.random.randint(10)

    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)

  return xs, ys

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 2), (0, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 2), (1, 0), rowspan=3, colspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 2), (4, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 2), (4, 1), rowspan=1, colspan=1)

x, y = random_plots()
ax1.plot(x, y)

x, y = random_plots()
ax2.plot(x, y)

x, y = random_plots()
ax3.plot(x, y)

x, y = random_plots()
ax4.plot(x, y)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Nothing in my usage has changed. I get the same behaviour in Google Colab notebooks and in my local Anaconda Jupiter notebooks.

Fairly sure the code is fine, because the above code is from the tutorials.

You can try this here: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/charts.ipynb#scrollTo=MXVPkFpTfCE-

I have been using Google Colab notebooks extensively and these plots worked until last week. Has something changed?

Comment: My original issue was with plt.imshow()

Comment: Does it work without `%matplotlib inline`?

Comment: No it doesn’t. 
Seems to be related to this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6675

Comment: Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Google Colab is now plotting with Matplotlib again. Not sure what has changed in the backend.